# window.settimeout functionality not working properly in ios safari and android browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

In our application, we are using the popup to show session expiration after 1 hour. Below is the code snippet.

```
    var sessionTimeout= window.setTimeout(functnTimeout, 36000);
    
   function functnTimeout() 
    {
    var timeouttemplate= somehtmlScriptId;
    
    $.model(timeouttemplate,{
    escclose: false, 
    closehtml: '' 
    containerClass: someClassName;
    } 
    }
```

It is perfectly in **chrome** regardless the web page tab is focussed or not.

But in **safari** and **android** version, we are not getting this popup and it is causing bad user experience. Since the user can see the same page after many hours and can able to proceed but in backend this transaction is going to fail. How could we fix the problem?

Comment: shouldn't it be setTimeout ? At the same time, this is bad design. you should probably use window.addEventListener("focus") to check validity of cookie

Comment: `settimeout(functnTimeout, 36000)` instant of `setTimeout(functnTimeout, 36000)`

Comment: I'm surprised this code works at all in any browser. It's `setTimeout`, not `settimeout`, and that's not how a function is declared.

Comment: Sry about the typo.Have corrected now.  using as setTimeout only.